Setting up Activiti but getting an error with classpath
I'm trying to configure a local environment to use Activiti and I'm getting an error.
Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined.

I've read on some sites where it says the config file has to be set in the classpath. How do I accomplish this?
Is there a class within Activiti to load the config file like how Spring ApplicationContext can be loaded through the ClassLoader?
What is the recommended approach to accomplish this?
 ProcessEngine processEngine 
          = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
        RepositoryService repositoryService 
          = processEngine.getRepositoryService();


Error log, 
17:40:20.189 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'processEngineConfiguration'
17:40:20.510 [main] ERROR org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines - Exception while initializing process engine: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in InputStream resource [resource loaded through InputStream]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jobExecutorActivate' of bean class [org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration]: Bean property 'jobExecutorActivate' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in InputStream resource [resource loaded through InputStream]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jobExecutorActivate' of bean class [org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration]: Bean property 'jobExecutorActivate' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

